# Speeding up Integrate and the numerical solution

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I want to compute the drag of a plate
[image]

Below is the code I am using to integrate the function

```
velcenter = {dotx, doty, 0};                     
 r = {Cos[θ[t]], Sin[θ[t]], 0};
veltanA = {-Sin[θ[t]], Cos[θ[t]], 0};
 velxpoint = Part[Cross[velcenter, r], 3];
 dragD = 1/2*ρ*cofD*h*Integrate[(Abs[velxpoint - s*dotθ])*(velcenter + 
                                       s*dotθ*veltanA), {s, a - l, a}];
```

The integration is so slow and I want to speed it up. Any suggestions are welcome !

Comment: conbine the Abs functon and the integrate function .the runing time is unbelievable

Comment: Is your integrand intended to be a scalar or a vector ?

Comment: integrand is a vector,3-D

Comment: The difficulty lies in the integral variable in Norm function,it makes the running time longer

Answer (score 3):

`Integrate` seems to prefer Sqrt[x^2] instead of Abs[x].
It also is wise to suppress `Sin` and `Cos` temporarily.
I would assume you do know for which parameters your integrand is
valid, thus you can use `GenerateConditions -> False`.
Then:

```
velcenter = {dotx, doty, 0};
r = {Cos[θ[t]], Sin[θ[t]], 0};
veltanA = {-Sin[θ[t]], Cos[θ[t]], 0};
velxpoint = Part[Cross[velcenter, r], 3];
SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> False];
dragD = 1/2*ρ*cofD*h*
    Inactive[Integrate][(Abs[velxpoint - s*dotθ])*(velcenter + s*dotθ*veltanA), 
              {s, a - l, a}] /.Cos -> Inactive[Cos] /. Sin -> Inactive[Sin]

AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Activate[Activate[dragD /. Abs :> (Sqrt[#^2] &), Integrate]] /. 
   Sqrt[zz_^2] :> Abs[zz]]
```

gives, after about half a minute (on my 2011 laptop) with Mathematica 10.3

[image]

You can check a specific point, e.g.:

```
Activate[
  (dragD==res) /. {dotx -> .2, doty -> .3, θ[t]-> 2., ρ->.2,
                   a-> 2.4,h-> 3.,l-> .9, dotθ-> .6,cofD -> .6}
]
```